# Get an array of only the IDs from matched records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

How can I get an array of just the IDs from the statement `User.where(some_criteria: true)`?

If I do `User.where(some_criteria: true).select(:id)` I get a `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation` object.

Comment: Try using [`pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck). For example, `User.where(some_criteria: true).pluck(:id)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `pluck` to get array of ID's like this:

```
User.where(some_criteria: true).pluck(:id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a Model **User**

I can do the following:

```
@User.where(myCriteria:true).select(:id)  #Assume this gives me the following ids: [3, 9]
arrayR = [];
@User.each do |i|
  arrayR << i.id
end

puts arrayR  # Will return [3, 9] as an array object.
```

arrayR will have an array of my identities.

A shorthand version of this can be accomplished by the following as well:

```
@user = User.all.pluck(:id)
puts @user.kind_of?(Array)  #returns true
puts @user #returns an array of my id's. Using the previous example, this returns [3,9]
```